# Django testing ajax endpoint in view

Tags: python, ajax, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I'm using [django-ajax](https://github.com/hhauer/django-ajax) in a django application, and want to do more thorough unit testing of the view that uses it.

My template for a particular view contains the following:

```
{% block head_js %} 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({
            value: false
        });

        var checkStatus = function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/ajax/MyApp/check_provisioning.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.data.complete != true) {
                        setTimeout(checkStatus, 3000);
                    } else {
                        // We've finished provisioning, time to move along.
                        window.location.replace('/MyApp/next');
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        checkStatus();
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

In MyApp/endpoints.py I have the function (simplified):

```
def check_provisioning(request):

    # Do some stuff                

    return {'complete': some_boolean}
```

Now... As far as I can tell, the view functions just fine, in actual usage.
But when making unit tests, django's test client retrieves the rendered response, but doesn't run anything embedded therein.

Does anyone know a way I can unit test that the view and/or the endpoint function are actually doing what they're supposed to? I would rather not fall back on using the django test framework to set up for a selenium test for the one view in the whole project that uses django-ajax this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like django-casper:

https://github.com/dobarkod/django-casper

I haven't used it, but it appears to be a django-specific python library which interfaces with CasperJS and PhantomJS.

PhantomJS is a web-kit based headless browser that gives a more light-weight alternative to browser automation with selenium.

Comment: I could, yes.

But if you'll notice the last paragraph of my question, I'm specifically looking for ways to not have to use selenium.

Comment: Thank you, that's an improvement over setting up a selenium test. It still feels like overkill for testing one function in one view template, but that might be the best I can expect short of writing a bunch of custom stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's any easy way to test client-side javascript unless you have some kind of headless browser or automated browser setup.